# REST API - Sforce-Limit-Info header not returned

Tags: rest-api, governorlimits, limits, release

I'm using SFDC's REST API to access org data. According to the docs (https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/headers_api_usage.htm), each request to the REST API should return a Sforce-Limit-Info header stating the the amount of API requests used, and the amount of remaining requests (on the 24 hours period).

I used curl to perform a test request to the "versions" REST resource, something like this

```
curl https://naxx.salesforce.com/services/data/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer accesstoken'
```

The first request returned the Sforce-Limit-Info header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 20 Oct 2014 15:02:23 GMT
Set-Cookie: BrowserId=xxx;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Fri, 19-Dec-2014 15:02:23 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Sforce-Limit-Info: api-usage=2/15000
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Then I performed the same exact request again, but this one didn't return the header.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 20 Oct 2014 15:39:14 GMT
Set-Cookie: BrowserId=xxx;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Fri, 19-Dec-2014 15:39:14 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Subsequent requests do not return the header either.

According to the docs the header should be returned on **ALL** requests, but this isn't the case. Anyone has experienced this issue? Is there anything I should do to ensure the header is included in the HTTP response? If this is a bug, do you know of any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens only with the *"Versions"* resource (/). The header is not returned, AND the request doesn't count against the limit. Any other resource, like *"Resources by Version"* (/vXX.X/), *"Limits"* (/vXX.X/limits/), *"Query"* (/vXX.X/query/), etc. will return the header, and the request will count against the API limit.

Comment: This is probably because you don't even need to be authenticated to call the versions resource.